M-x shell launches shell and then hangs after running shell command
Working on source code in Emacs 28.2 on Mac, shell command M-! works as expected, and the command runs fine.
The command M-x shell successfully launches a shell window, but then after running a shell command (such as ls -l), Emacs hangs.  I have to force quit.  I am running bash shell.  I am also getting this behavior in Aquamacs.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Working on source code in Emacs 28.2... - what does that mean? Does it mean you built Emacs from source? When the shell window is launched, do you get a prompt where you type the ls -l or is there no prompt?

oh, sorry.  I am just working in emacs writing some source code.  I want to launch a shell window so I can compile the code there.  Yes, I get a > prompt.  The shell command runs.  Then emacs is unresponsive...ESC, C-D, C-Z, C-C, nothing will nudge it, not even Quit Emacs from the menu bar.  If I leave it for many minutes (not sure exactly how many), it gets unstuck.

Is this on Windows?

Does force quit mean you pressed C-g and that stopped the spinning?

No, on macos.  Force quit via OPT-CMD-Shift.

I don't know what that does: does it kill Emacs or interrupt its spinning? Is >  your primary prompt? I'm asking because usually $  is the primary prompt in bash and >  is a secondary prompt (although they can be customized).

I'd be willing to bet it's something with your shell's setup. Start with a reduced (or no) init, or disable fancy features. Very early in my ZSH init, at top of my ~/.zshrc I have:
  ## tramp gets hung up on precmd(), unset some features
  if [[ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]]; then
     unsetopt zle
     unsetopt prompt_cr
     unsetopt prompt_subst
     unfunction precmd
     unfunction preexec
     PS1='$ '
     return
  fi

Note the basic prompt, and that we bail out of initialization with the return. In fact, that's probably all you'd need for Bash.

Note, that I reference tramp in snippet's comment, but this would apply to M-x shell as well, as the both set TERM to "dumb".
